# How to return a hash after using sort_by in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

When I use `sort_by` on the frequency hash, it returns an array.  How do I return a hash instead?

```
puts frequency.class        #returns hash
frequency = frequency.sort_by {|k,v| v}.reverse
puts frequency.class        #returns array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) just returns an array. You can cast it back to a hash like this:

```
frequency = frequency.sort_by {|k,v| v}.reverse
frequency = Hash[frequency]
```

Comment: I don't think I'd call that casting, but yeah, this is the solution.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in 1.9.3.  The hash 'order' (via `each`) changes, but it's not sorted.

Comment: @JimStewart That approach works fine for me under `ruby 1.9.3`. I tried this code for instance: `h = {:fernando => 28,:john => 18,:peter => 54}`
`Hash[h.sort_by { |name, age| age }.reverse]`

Comment: Weird..I get `peter`, `fernando`, `john` as the order if I do that.

Comment: That's the correct result. See the `.reverse` at the end. It would give you the values order by age starting by the oldest onto the youngest.

Comment: For me it works in both 1.9.3 and 2.0.0. @JimStewart, you are talking about keys, but asker seems to want to sort on values. Which is what fmendez' example does too: a reverse sort on age.

Comment: Some day I will learn to read all the words.  I was in fact looking at keys and not values.  Note that hash order was not defined prior to Ruby 1.9.2 (no guarantee of order), but as of 1.9.2 order is retained.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old question, but using Ruby 2.2+ it's pretty simple:

```
frequency.sort_by { |_, v| -v }.to_h
```